# Is there a closed form of $\sum_{i=1}^{n-k} {n-1-i\choose k-1}x^i$ in $x$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, generating-functions

I'm looking for the generating function of the sum  $\sum_{i=1}^{n-k} {n-1-i\choose k-1}x^i$. One can compute this using the Euler-MacLauren formula but the remainder term is a little messy. Is there a quick or easy way to compute this completely?
I ask because a closed form of this would imply the closed form of the $(n^m,1)$ Pascal triangles, and the basic formula for the $(a_n,b_n)$ Pascal triangles doesn't give the full closed form.

Comment: A closed formula does not seem feasible here.

Comment: You have already asked this in [Closed form of $ \sum_{i=1}^{n-k} {n-1-i\choose k-1}i^a + \sum_{i=1}^k {n-1-i\choose n-1-k}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395327/closed-form-of-sum-i-1n-k-n-1-i-choose-k-1ia-sum-i-1k-n-1-i-ch)

Comment: This question is different in structure.

Comment: Then you need elaborate what is different and/or why you are not happy with answers given there.

Comment: In that question I was looking for ${n-2\choose k-1}1^a + {n-3\choose k-1}2^a...+{k-1\choose k-1}(n-k)^a$ but here I'm looking for ${n-2\choose k-1}x + {n-3\choose k-1}x^2...+{k-1\choose k-1}x^{n-k}$.

Comment: Essentially you ask for truncation of the series $\sum_{m\geq k-1} \binom{m}{k-1} y^{m-k+1} = (1-y)^{-k}$. There seems to be no nice formula here.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your notion of "closed" is.  A quick calculation in Mathematica shows that your expression equals

$x{n-2\choose k-1}\cdot {}_2 F_1(1,1+k-n;2-n;x)$,

where ${}_2 F_1$ denotes the Gaussian [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).  These are well-understood in many contexts.